# What is the solution to the problem of running a check50?

Tags: cs50

**When I turn on check50 and submit50 affiliated to CS50  gives me this error**

```
 $ check50 cs50/problems/2020/x/sentimental/cash
 check50: command not found
```

Is this an error in downloading the tool? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is it installed? https://cs50.readthedocs.io/projects/check50/en/latest/

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, of course, I installed check50 & submit50 and it all give me the same error

Comment: From that error message, it looks like the executable is not in your path or not installed. You might get better response if you ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/